# Vue.js + Chartist: Using charts in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chartist.js

I have a component that has access to the data necessary to generate a [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) graph but I'm not sure how to generate the chart.  Here's my component:

```
Vue.component('chart-card', {
  template: "#chart-card",
  props: {
    location: Object,
    appointments: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {

    fetchAppointments: function() {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        data: { location_id: this.location.id },
        url: `/appointments.json`,
        success: function(res) {
          that.data = {
            labels: Object.keys(res),
            seried: Object.values(res)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and `data` becomes something like:

```
data: {
  labels: [
    "Consultation",
    "Weekly Sessions",
    "Re-Eval Week",
    "Full Maintenance",
    "Limited Maintenance",
    "Re-Starting the Program"
  ],
  series: [4, 24, 3, 1, 4, 1]
}
```

I run into the issue when I try to generate the chart which requires a DOM element:

```
new Chartist.Pie(DOM_ELEMENT_HERE, data, options )
```

Where would I make that call in a Vue component?

Comment: You really shouldn't making async calls in a computed value. Can you show what your template looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data fetch does not belong in a computed property, it should be a method call instead as it is asynchronous. The value for `fetchAppointments` will always be `undefined` in your case.

You can construct your graph in the [`mounted` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) and refer to the appropriate DOM node using the [`$el` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el).

My version of what you're trying to do would look like:

```
Vue.component({
  template: "#chart-card",

  props: {
    location: Object,
    appointments: Object
  },

  methods: {
    fetchAppointments() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          data: { location_id: this.location.id },
          url: `/appointments.json`,
          
          success: res => resolve({
            labels: Object.keys(res),
            seried: Object.values(res)
          })
        });
      });
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchAppointments().then(data => {
      new Chartist.Pie(this.$el, data, options);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks like the he is getting data asynchronously.

Comment: @BertEvans I can expand the answer to include putting the fetch for data in the right place but the question asked specifically about where to call the `Chartist.Pie` constructor and how to refer to the appropriate DOM node.

Comment: My point is, creating the chart in mounted won't work if the data isn't available.

Comment: @BertEvans There.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  I thought `mounted()` applied to a `Vue` instance and not the components.  Makes much more sense this way

Comment: @JeremyThomas Components are Vue instances :-)